# Why does Facebook send the signed request via POST?

Tags: javascript, facebook, request, signed

Why does Facebook send the signed request via POST ?
Indeed if the signed request were sent via GET it will allow client-side javascript code to get it. Thereby the application could be stored in a unique static html file.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

1) It's a lot easier to copy/paste a url containing GET parameters compared to a URL sent with POST parameters. That is why most sensitive information is sent through POST and not GET. (Note - it's not "safer" in terms of transmission, it just wont appear in normal server logs and is not easy to copy). Sharing the URL with signed request is not something you want to do, and Facebook presumably feel the same way so make it easier for you to not do it accidentally.

2) As a general rule, GETs should be used to influence state, but not to make any permanent changes to data. POSTS should be used when making changes. As Facebook don't know if you're going to update a database based on the signed_request, they send as POST - which is the correct thing to do.